# GKE - Multiple Namespaces at usecase level- possible?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, multi-tenant

Just starting up with GKE. So please bear with
In GKE, a NodeJS application is hosted to perform a function. It has a service account associated with it. Multiple processes (usecase processes) will call it simultaneously.

- Can we have multiple usecase level namespaces so as to have 1 service account per usecase?
- If yes, will that need multiple application instance deployment? or can 1 instance be associated with multiple SA?
- Which multi-tenancy will that be called - SaaS or enterprise?

thanks

Comment: Hi `adiideas` can you explain it by using some architectural diagram or add some more explanation like why you need to use multiple SA etc…

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni Thanks for reply. We need to implement isolation at process level. So If 3 processes are calling that application, we want each one to have its own Service account.  Processes will not be adhoc, we would know before hand that a particular proecss is getting onboarded.